# Getting a config file outside of a jar file?

Tags: java, config

I want to open a `.config` file outside of the `.jar` file so that I can use its properties inside of the `.jar`. How would I do this?

Comment: Yes you can do this, first take the jar file's path or installation path than the properties file to load

Comment: Where is "outsinde of the jar file"? Can you build a `Path` to the location?

Answer (score 1):

For clearance you will use a config file from the (executable) jar like this:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(in);
```

that loads config.properties relative to the class of the current object.

For a config outside you propably use a file:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+"config.properties");
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(in);
```

Comment: I get file unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must caught or declared to be thrown.

Comment: This is not a complete example. Exception handling is for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
String path  = System.getProperty("user.dir")
path += "/config/myApp.properties"
```

Now you have the path of your properties file.
You know what to do next